# ng-model not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why the ng-model is not working with the ng-repeat.

There is my code:

```
$scope.availableCountries = [];
APIUtility.getCountries().then(function(data){
    $scope.availableCountries = data;
    $scope.filters.country = "AZ";
});


<select id="eventprice" class="searchpage_select" ng-model="filters.country">
    <option value="all">show all</option>
    <option ng-repeat="countries in availableCountries" value="{{countries.country_iso}}" ng-class="{'element_selected' : filters.country == countries.country_iso}">{{countries.name}}</option>
</select>
```

where:

`availableCountries` is an object from an API call (well formed, trust me)

`$scope.filters` is an object containing a lot of filters (including country)

The problem is that if i change the `ng-model` before or after the API call, the select statement is not updated, i think that if i update the scope before angular has the time to execute his `ng-repeat`, `ng-model` stop working and will not update the field.

i added the `ng-class` to prove that `filters.country` has the right value (`ng-class` statement returns true when needed and add the class in the right place, so `filters.country` contains the right value).

I don't know if i was clear enough. Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-options` instead of an `ng-repeat` on an `option` field.

```
<select id="eventprice" 
        class="searchpage_select" 
        ng-model="filters.country"
        ng-options="country.country_iso as country.name for country in availableCountries">
    <option value="all">show all</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, but i need to put the ```country_iso``` inside the ```value``` attribute, right now he's add a sort of incremental counter as value ```<option value="0" selected="selected" label="Andorra">Andorra</option>``` while i need something like ```<option value="AN" selected="selected" label="Andorra">Andorra</option>```

Comment: i took a look into the docs and it seems that the first declaration should be the value (so ```country.country_iso as...```) but is not showing me the right value. I also tried ```country.country_iso as country.country_iso for country in availableCountries``` (in order to have the country_iso in value and label) and it shows me the iso as label but still this "counter" in value

Comment: Yes, how I have it *should* put `country_iso` as the value -- if you can post a fiddle or jsbin or something I can see what's going wrong.

Comment: something like -> http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14994/ even if my code is a bit more complicated. As you can see, the ```all``` option doesn't exist. the first one is empty with ```value="?"``` if i preset the model with ```all``` and the value are integer. I also tried to preset the model with a valid iso and it works. so i think i don't have to care about the values... I think the only thing is the ```all``` field that is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in 
`$scope.filters.country = "AZ";`

Try this updated jsfiddle

`http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15021/`